# Help with Joomla 1.5 banners

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I want to have different categories of banners displaying depending on which page (menu item) is chosen.

So I have 2 categories of banners (cat1 and cat2) set up, same client for both, and each with several banners in them.

I have 2 menu modules set up (group1 and group2), group1 is assigned cat1 and menu HOME, and group2 is assigned cat2 and menu PRODUCTS. Both modules as set to position "banner".

I have a position in my template for a banner:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="banner" style="xhtml" />
```

The banners on the HOME page show exactly as expected, but no banner is on PRODUCTS page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you assigning the banner to the PRODUCTS page in the Module's "Menu Assignment"?  And make sure the banner is assigned to the proper category. Simple but overlooked sometimes.

Comment: Yes, banner is assigned to Products page in using the corresponding menu item, and the banner is in the right category. Is what I am trying to do possible with the standard banner module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stock banner tools that come with Joomla do a good job, but I don't think they'll meet your needs.

Check out : http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/ads-a-affiliates/banner-management/6951

While not the most elegant (You need to manage the component AND module) it has good flexibility, like what it seems you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go with that extension. Still seems odd to me that I can't get the standard banners to work in this fashion - it's not complicated, just different 'sets' of banners for different pages.